# ruby pipe operator

Tags: ruby, operators, pipe

I'm new to ruby, and I saw this code snippet

```
1|2
```

and it returns 3

What does the `|` operator actually do? I couldn't seem to find any documentation on it. Also, in this context is it referred to as the "pipe" operator? or is it called something else?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Ruby, "operators" are actually method calls. They are defined by each class.

1 and 2 are Fixnum and so in `1|2` pipe does "bitwise or".

[Ruby doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Fixnum.html#method-i-7C)

[Bitwise info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

Comment: oops, yeah, I didn't even think about bitwise or. when I saw 1|2 and the result was 3, my thought immediately went to addition so that's what confused me about it.

Answer (score 32):

This is a bitwise operator and they work directly with the binary representation of the value.

`|` mean OR. Let me show you how it works.

`1|2 = 3`
what happens under the hoods is:

```
1 = 0001
2 = 0010
--------
3 = 0011 <- result
```

another example:

`10|2 = 10`
now in binary:

```
10 = 1010
2  = 0010
--------
10 = 1010 <- result
```

Answer (score 2):

It is the bitwise or operator.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Ruby/Language-Basics/dobitwiseoperationsinRuby.htm

Comment: Ah yes, same as many other languages...don't know why I thought it did something else, thanks.